# MySql performance, FROM_UNIXTIME vs Parse in PHP to date string

Tags: php, mysql, performance

There are similar questions to this one in SO bot not quite what I want to know.

I have an insert statement that looks like this:

```
insert into my_table (id, time) values
(1, from_unixtime(1495488539)),
(2, from_unixtime(1495488539)),
...
(99, from_unixtime(1495488539)),
(100, from_unixtime(1495488539));
```

That timestamp was obtained with php with like this: `$time = time()`.

It looks to me like that function will be executed for every row in the insert, and it sounds inefficient.

My other option is to generate the time like this in php: `$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and my insert statements will look like this:

```
insert into my_table (id, time) values
(1, '2017-05-22 21:28:59'),
(2, '2017-05-22 21:28:59'),
...
(99, '2017-05-22 21:28:59'),
(100, '2017-05-22 21:28:59');
```

That one looks simpler because there are no function calls on each row, but MySQL still parses each time the string, right?

**The question is which of the two flavors should I use to have better performance?**

Why I don't simply use `current_timestamp` or `now()`? because the date must be the same for all rows, and I don't do a single insert, I spread it in many different smaller insert statements, so in reality my php looks more like `$time = $global_time_same_for_all_rows_not_exactly_now`. In other words, that time is treated kind of like an import-key of some sort.

Comment: Your first query is calling `from_unixtime(1495488539)` for every row, which is obviously going to be slower than simply inserting a string. The difference is going to be negligible unless you're inserting hundreds of thousands of values, however.

Comment: Just a note but if there's a timezone difference between your mysql server and php server, I believe that your mysql from_unixtime(timestamp value) and php date function could produce different results. With that said, it looks like you are working with a datetime field so it's probably simpler to just pass date strings over.

Comment: @georaldc does that matter? isn't the output of php's `time()` function supposed to be absolute in all the world? unless I am mistaken, it is when you parse it into a readable date that the timezone is taken into account, right?

Comment: @georaldc proved. I ran this exact same command in my pc and in a remote server and both gave different results, which proves that it doesn't matter where you call `time()`, but where you call either `date()` (in php) or `from_unixtime()` (in mysql):
`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1495488539);`

Comment: @georaldc aaand, after re-reading your comment, I think we are both in the same understanding, I just had missunderstood your point. And yes, both are in the same timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning date() to $time, and then using that variable repeatedly in multiple insert statements will be less overhead.

Using time() in php and then using from_unixtime in mysql to convert back to a datetime is an additional unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1):

This one is *probably* optimized:

```
insert into my_table (id, time) values
    (1, NOW()),
    (2, NOW()), ...;
```

That is because *certain* functions are deliberately evaluated once before a statement -- NOW, UNIX_TIMESTAMP, UUID?, and a few others, but not RAND.

But, all of this is mostly irrelevant.  The overhead of performing the row inserts (or selects, etc) far exceeds the trivial time it takes to perform `from_unixtime(1495488539)`, or virtually any other simple function.  It's possibly the difference between milliseconds versus sub-microsecond timing.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have seen in my "rudimentary" tests but I couldn't reach a conclusion, this helps.